# Set a white background color for rendering

Tags: rendering, image

I want my rendering to have a white background. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Under world properties there is a Surface section where one can set the color for the surface "Background". Does this do what I want? And also is it a good way to do this?

Comment: Why you don't try it yourself, when you know? Yes if you want a white color on render do it as you wrote.

Comment: I tried it, but still I don't know whether it is properly "working". I searched on the internet for how to set a white background and the results showed way more complex solutions to just have a white background. So I was not sure, whether my solution is intended for that purpose or does not really work or has some disadvantages for example.

Comment: Well that depends what you expect, or what you want to achieve. I would use just transparent background so i can choose the background i Photoshop. But the environment can be reflected on object and can have a effect on its color, so if white helps you in this purpose use white. It just depends on what result you want.

Comment: Ah, ok. So normally the background is transparent, so it can be edited later. Did not know that, thought the background was grey by default. Since I want to setup a batch rendering script, it is probably more convenient to set the background right away, so it does not have to be changed later. Plus I have the benefit of it interacting with the object (did not know that, thanks for pointing it out).

Comment: It is grey by default, however @Fowl sets his/her surface to transparent for his/her own needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes and yes.

[image]

If you change your viewport shading to Render Preview:

[image]

Or change the Viewport Shading to show the Scene World, you will see the rendered result of your background selection.

[image]

Comment: This worked too when baking textures with cycles. The shadows were being baked with a pink color tint. In UVEditing and TexturePaint, I noticed the background was all pink. Then I thought the background could be being reflected in the object as pink reflection (or interfering in the shadows in some other way). When I set a black background, the baking worked perfectly, thx!

Answer (score 2):

For older version:

- Switch Engine to Cycle Render. Go to World tab in Properties panel. Locate to Surface Section and click Use Nodes. Finally pick your color.

[image: Switch to Cycle Render. Goto World tab in Properties panel. Locate to Surface Section and click Use Nodes. Then pick your color.]

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to get a 100% white background in Blender 4.0 with either Cycles or Eevee (not light gray as the other answers posted before mine will give you):

1. Go to *World Properties* in the properties panel and make sure the *Color* is set to white. *Use Nodes* can either be off entirely or on with a *Background* shader selected as the surface material.

[image: Step 1 image 1]  [image: Step 1 image 2]

2. Go to *Render Properties* and under *Color Management*, select *Standard* as your *View Transform*.

[image: Step 2]