# White background viewport render image instead of grey

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, image

I want to use this material preview by using viewport render image how do i make the background white and not dark grey?

[image]

Comment: In Material Preview, in the Viewport Shading panel, you can enable Scene World, then in the Properties panel > World, set a World color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a white background color for rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167554/set-a-white-background-color-for-rendering)    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222047/viewport-render-image-how-to-render-custom-background-color

Answer (score 2):

In *Material Preview*, in the *Viewport Shading* panel, you can enable *Scene World*:

[image]

Then in the *Properties panel > World*, set a world color:

[image]